# $=require('jQuery') results in 'window not defined'. What to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb, kanso

I am fiddling around with a 'list'-function in couch handling linked documents. Documents and their linked 'neighbors' are screened. It works all fine.

So, I thought I would extend it a little and let some representative 'neighbor'-data be screened rather than the _id:xxx..

My thought was to use jQuery.ajax() and feed it the _id:xxx to return the data I wanted and then let the list-function send that to be screened.

In the top of the 'lib/lists.js' I place `$=require('jQuery')` and in the kanso.json the jquery package is included and 'installed' before the push *but* this only results in `window not defined`.

OK. It could be that there does not exist any window-object in the lists.js, but what to do then? Should I write an XHRHttpRequest in javascript directly or let lists.js result on a webpage where jQuery can be called in the `<script>jQuery code here..</script>` and find the elements wanted, read the _id:xxx, fetch wanted data and replace _id:xxx with the wanted data?

Both solutions seems rather 'write more, don't do so much actually'. Suggestions?

Comment: @Tushar I appreciate your concern with my spelling except that it causes confusion as the spelling is not mine.
For future reference:
http://kan.so/packages/details/jquery
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neighbour

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing....
My workaround was to move the jquery Requires statement to my index.html page and reduce the require definition from

```
var db = require('db').current();
```

to

```
var db = require('db');
```

This worked, but I'm not saying its idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as far as I got it:
No jQuery, no XHR, not anything side effecting in that direction in _list functions.

My solution: Write separate jQuery code requesting a view and then with the retrieved _id:s to the linked document do separate requests for data from linked docs.

Disclaimer: I have NOT been able to make `$.couch.db().openDoc()` return any document. Instead I used `$.get()` with great success.